# Trying to use stored procedures in winforms. the visual studio 2015 says that there is an error close toy ", "

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio, stored-procedures

here is the code:
                           i've tried to make it bold. is in ", " part.

```
InitializeComponent();
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=casodeestudio;integrated security=true");
conexion.Open();
string auxiliar1 = (string)textBox1.Text;
string auxiliar2 = (string)textBox2.Text;
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("spObtenerMarca " + auxiliar1 + ", " + auxiliar2 + "", conexion);
//comando.CommandText("");
SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: There are a thousand questions here about how to all a stored procedure, go find some of them. What you are doing here is not only wrong, it's dangerous (go look up SQL injection attacks)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
+ **bold**", "
```

Should read:

```
+ **bold** + ", "
```

Although I have no idea what ** bold** is

Comment: haha, thanks, thats because i tried to make bold the error, that was not in the original code.

Answer (score -1):

If your stored procedure is expecting varchar or char parameters you need to surround the parameters with single quotes.

```
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("spObtenerMarca '" + auxiliar1 + "', '" + auxiliar2 + "'", conexion
```

@DavidG makes a valid point about SQL injection. You should change your code to use parameters instead of concatonating and passing a command string.

Per criticism for not including an example:

```
...
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("spObtenerMarca", conexion);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter1", auxiliar1);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter2", auxiliar2);
SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
...
```

[MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It'd be better to show OP how to use Command Parameters to fend off SQL Injection hacks..  Not sure how OP even got that code to compile with double quotes.